# message "no module named compose" in docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

I tried already `pip install docker-compose`
But it didn't help...
Didn't find any other solution for this question, any clue greatly appreciated
(Running docker 20.10.18 on raspbian bullseye, can't provide compose version, same error)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's due to a bad installation of multiple versions of python unfortunately.
Trying to uninstall 3.10 which has been installed manually above the standard 3.9 package and screws up everything...